# Upsert embedded document in yiimongodbsuite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii-extensions, yii

I need to perform an upsert command in yiimongodbsuite.
I tried

```
$model   = new Murls();          
                $model->userid=$userid;
                $model->title=$title;      
                $model->edits[0] = new Medithtml();
                $model->edits[0]->path= $htm;
                $model->edits[0]->html=$path;
                $model->edits[0]->ci=$ci;
                $model->update(array('_id'=>$rec->_id ),array('userid', 'title','edits' ), true );
```

But this shows an error.

Murls model is defined as follows

```
   class Murls extends EMongoDocument
    {
        public $userid;
        public $title;
        public $edits;



   public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
      {
        return parent::model($className);
      }

      // This method is required!
      public function getCollectionName()
      {
        return 'murls';
      }

      public function attributeLabels()
      {
        return array(
          'html'=>'Html',
        );
      }

      public function embeddedDocuments()
      {
        return array(
                // property name => embedded document class name
                'edits'=>'Medithtml',

        );
      }

      public function behaviors(){
            return array(
                            'embeddedArrays' => array(
                                'class' => 'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.extra.EEmbeddedArraysBehavior',
                                'arrayPropertyName' => 'edits', // name of property, that will be used as an array
                                'arrayDocClassName' => 'Medithtml'    // class name of embedded documents in array
                ),
        );
      }

    }
```

and model  Medithtml as

```
class Medithtml extends EMongoEmbeddedDocument{
    public $html;
    public $path;
    public $ci;

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }


}
```

What I need to achieve is that a record with `$title` can have n number of `$html`  , `$path` and `$ci`.
Any help will be appreciated.
What I am looking is to store data like this

```
     array (
  '_id' => 
  MongoId::__set_state(array(
     '$id' => '51ee1956d39c2c7e078d80da',
  )),
  'userid' => '12',
  'title' => 'Mongo',
  'edits' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'html' => 'html>body>div:nth-child(2)>a>div>a>div',
      'path' => 'ssssss',
      'ci' => '1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'html' => 'html>body>div:nth-child(2)>a>div:nth-child(3)>a>h2',
      'path' => '/assets/img/demo/demo-avatar9604.jpg',
      'ci' => '2',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'html' => ' html>body>div:nth-child(2)>a>div:nth-child(3)>a>center:nth-child(16)>a>h1',
      'path' => '333',
      'ci' => '3',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Only the comments array will be updated if record with a particular combination of `'title'` and `'userid'` exists.If it doesn not exists a new record will be inserted

Comment: I do not think this complex an upsert can be done through active record, I think you may have to do it via actually touching the database. YiiMongoDBSuite does not know that the subdocument is to be upserted and attempts to make it do so would probably result in sub-optimal coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution in this way:

```
       $rec = $model->find($criteria)  ;
           if($rec){

       foreach($rec->edits as  $editarray){
            $var[]=$editarray;
       }
        $edits_new= new Medithtml();
        $edits_new['html']=$htm;
        $edits_new['ci']=$ci;
        $edits_new['path']=$path;  
        $var[]=$edits_new;
        $rec->edits=$var;

        $rec->userid=$userid;
        $rec->title=$title;
        $rec->update(array('edits'  ), true);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are inheriting from wrong class. To save document you must inherit from `EMongoDocument` not `EMongoEmbeddedDocument`. These classes are similar but have different purpose.

- `EMongoEmbeddedDocument` Is for embedded documents only, it should be used only for embedded documents
- `EMongoDocument` extends from `EMongoEmbeddedDocument` with methods to actually save data to db.

For array of comments, you have two options:

1. Use plain php array - simple less maintanable, less power, erron prone..
2. Use [array of embedded documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#hh10) - each comment is document, so can be validated, has rigid structure etc.

By default `save`/`insert`/`update` stores all attributes. For partial updates use combination of `$attributes` and set `$modify` to true. **Warning**: Passing array of attributes without `$modify` will store only passed attributes, discarding rest of document.

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributes = null)
...
public function insert(array $attributes = null)
...
public function update(array $attributes = null, $modify = false)
...
```

So in your case you can update like that:

```
$model->update(array('comments'), true);
```

Or if it's ok for you to ovverride whole document just save:

```
$model->save();
```

**Note:** for composite pk ovverride `primaryKey()`:

```
public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('title', 'userid');
}
```

Uh, good that stackoverflow have drafts autosave feature:)

Comment: I think you have not understood my question fully.SO I have rewritten my question

Comment: Note point 2 about embedding. I meant array of embedded documents (not embedded array). But, default yii mongodb suite fork does not support it natively. I updated answer with link to docs about array of embedded documents. Array of embedded documents will store structure you need and will allow OO access in Yii. As second part of question, composite primary key and partial update should be fine.