# How to save embed document in Yii MongoDB Suite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I have 2 classes "`users`" and "`userName`"

```
class users extends EMongoDocument {

public $name;
public $address;

public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

// This method is required!
public function getCollectionName() {
    return 'users';
}

public function getMongoDBComponent() {
    return Yii::app()->mongodb;
}

public function behaviors() {
    return array(
        array(
            'class' => 'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.extra.EEmbeddedArraysBehavior',
            'arrayPropertyName' => 'name', // name of property
            'arrayDocClassName' => 'userName' // class name of documents in array
        ),
    );
}

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('name, address', 'required'),
        array('name, address', 'length', 'max' => 255),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'name' => 'Full name',
        'address' => 'Address',
    );
}
}
```

---

```
class userName extends EMongoEmbeddedDocument {

public $firstname;
public $middlename;
public $lastname;

public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

// This method is required!
public function getCollectionName() {
    return 'userName';
}

public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('firstname, middlename,lastname', 'required'),
        array('firstname, middlename,lastname', 'length', 'max' => 255),
    );
}

public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'firstname' => 'First Name',
        'middlename' => 'Middle Name',
        'lastname' => 'Last Name',
    );
}
}
```

I have code:

[image]

I can't save embed document. I have an error:

```
mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

[image]

Comment: If you search this site I remember a bounty question by the same title

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760038/upsert-embedded-document-in-yiimongodbsuite

Answer (score 0):

You have a validation rule of max length for the `name` attribute. This rule uses function `mb_strlen`. But for some reason you've wrote `$u->name[0] = new UserName()`, so you `name` attribute becomes an array, but not a string. That's the reason.